# TDD Inserting to Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd

I've been reading about TDD and I've seen a lot of posts about not to do any database transaction because "single, isolated block of code with no dependencies".

So now I have a little bit of dilemma - I  want to be able to test if my service layer method called `AddNewStudent` actually works. This method goes into my `DbContext` and then add a new record into the database. If database operations aren't recommended for TDD then how else can I test `AddNewStudent` method aside from just testing my application on a browser?

```
public class StudentManager : ManagerBase
{
    internal StudentManager() { }

    public Student AddNewStudent(string fName, string lName, DateTime dob)
    {
        // Create a student model instance using factory
        var record = Factories.StudentFac.CreateOne(fName, lName, dob);

        DbContext.Students.Add(record);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();

        return record;
    }
}
```

And my test looks like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void StudentManager_AddNewStudent_Test()
{
    var fName = "Ryan";
    var lName = "Rigil";
    var dob = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2006");

    var student = Managers.StudentManager.AddNewStudent(fName, lName, dob);

    Assert.AreEqual(fName, student.FirstName);
    Assert.AreEqual(lName, student.LastName);
    Assert.AreEqual(dob.ToShortDateString(), student.DoB.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Comment: Create an abstraction of your DbContext that you can mock up in your unit tests to verify the method under test

Comment: Added an example code above

Comment: The assumption here is that `DbContext` and `Factories` part of `ManagerBase`?

Comment: DbContext came from the EDMX file generated by EF6. I use factories to create model instance - just to make sure that everything is valid whenever i create an instance of a model.

Comment: Using static service locator anti-pattern makes testing your class more difficult. You should start trying to make them loosely  coupled by using abstraction so that you can create fake versions of them for better testing

Comment: Sorry but can you show me how to accomplish that in this kind of situation? Are we talking about interfaces here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StudentManager` has dependencies buried internally that make it difficult to test. Consider restructuring your design to allow for better testability.

Looking at the `StudentManager` the following assumptions were derived...

```
//An assumed abstraction of the ManagerBase
public abstract class ManagerBase {
    public ManagerBase(IDbContext dbContext, IFactory factories) {
        DbContext = dbContext;
        Factories = factories;
    }
    public IDbContext DbContext { get; private set; }
    public IFactory Factories { get; private set; }
}

//An abstraction of what the unit of work would look like
public interface IDbContext {
    //student repository
    DbSet<Student> Students { get; }
    //...other repositories
    int SaveChanges();
}

//Just an example of the Student Factory.
public interface IModelFactory<T> where T : class, new() {
    T Create(Action<T> configuration);
}

public interface IFactory {
    IModelFactory<Student> StudentFac { get; }
    //...other factories. Should try to make your factories Generic
}
```

With that the target class refactors to...

```
public class StudentManager : ManagerBase {
    public StudentManager(IDbContext dbContext, IFactory factories) : base(dbContext, factories) { }

    public Student AddNewStudent(string fName, string lName, DateTime dob) {
        // Create a student model instance using factory
        var record = Factories.StudentFac.Create(r => {
            r.FirstName = fName;
            r.LastName = lName;
            r.DoB = dob;
        });

        base.DbContext.Students.Add(record);
        base.DbContext.SaveChanges();

        return record;
    }
}
```

While it may look like much it will greatly help the testability of your code.

A mocking framework like `Moq` can now be used to create a fake version of the database access and factories...

```
[TestMethod]
public void StudentManager_Should_AddNewStudent() {
    //Arrange: setup/initialize the dependencies of the test
    var fName = "Ryan";
    var lName = "Rigil";
    var dob = DateTime.Parse("3006-01-03");

    //using Moq to create mocks/fake of dependencies
    var dbContextMock = new Mock<IDbContext>();

    //Extension method used to create a mock of DbSet<T>
    var dbSetMock = new List<Student>().AsDbSetMock();
    dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.Students).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);

    var factoryMock = new Mock<IFactory>();
    factoryMock
        .Setup(x => x.StudentFac.Create(It.IsAny<Action<Student>>()))
        .Returns<Action<Student>>(a => {
            var s = new Student();
            a(s);
            return s;
        });

    //this is the system/class under test.
    //while this is being created manually, you should look into
    //using DI/IoC container to manage Dependency Injection
    var studentManager = new StudentManager(dbContextMock.Object, factoryMock.Object);

    //Act: here we actually test the method
    var student = studentManager.AddNewStudent(fName, lName, dob);

    //Assert: and check that it executed as expected
    Assert.AreEqual(fName, student.FirstName);
    Assert.AreEqual(lName, student.LastName);
    Assert.AreEqual(dob.ToShortDateString(), student.DoB.ToShortDateString());
}
```

For production you can create proper implementations of the interfaces and inject them into the classes that depend on them. This answer is based entirely on the example you provided in your post. Take some time to understand the concepts used and also do some more research online. You can then apply these concepts with the remainder of your project as you progress with TDD.

Comment: Quick question... In my previous projects i would use abstracted UoW but since this one is going to use an EDMX file, is abstraction of UoW still necessary? Isn't that duplicated work?

Comment: Another thing is the reason I want to use factories is because whenever I create an instance of a Model (in this case a student) I don't have to guess which properties are required or not. With Action<T> there isn't really anything there that would stop me from creating an instance of a student without a first name and last name - a student with just DoB.

Comment: That was just an example based on the code in your original post. You can still create your own method that does what you intended initially.